# line-height does not work

Tags: html, css

First of all, I've setup a [page](http://jsbin.com/coqiboma/2/edit) where you can play around with my code.

I am attempting to center the text *Interview* in the middle of the red frame using the following CSS tag. However, it does not seem to have any affect. What am I doing wrong?

```
line-height: 100%;
```

Answer (score -2):

you can't use percentages with line-height. only a value is allowed (http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/)

do line-height: 1.5; and that centers the text within the red frame